# Selector jquery de javascript en typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, dom

Estoy aprendiendo a usar typescript y no entiendo porque no funciona

```
initHideCookies = (function (selector:string) {
    //Hide Cookies

    $(selector).click(function () {
        $(".m_cookie").hide();
    });
})
```

el $(selector) no se me reconoce, y el evento DOM de 'click' tampoco.
Se supone que en typescript acepta el lenguaje de javascript, asi que no entiendo porque sale ese error.

Comment: falta que indiques cual es el error, pero tambien ayudaria que expliques como importas jquery y en general como se construye la aplicacion transpilada.

Answer (score 3):

El símbolo $ es propio de jQuery, no del lenguaje JavaScript en sí.

jQuery es una librería que aporta una capa de abstracción por encima de JavaScript para facilitar muchas de sus funcionalidades. Para poder utilizarla, necesitas importarla, añadiéndolo en el `head` de tu documento `html`.

Para la versión 1.12 una posibilidad sería:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya conseguí solucionar este problema. Lo que he hecho era escribir lo siguiente a través la terminal dentro de mi proyecto (en mi caso, visual studio code tiene integrada la terminal):

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

y luego hacer un imports donde estes haciendo typescript:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

y ya funcionó.